# how to extract specific part of a string in java

Tags: java, regex, substring

consider this statement from a jsp file(there are many more statements like this in jsp file..)
Statement-

```
<h:dataGrid something styleclass="styleclass1" something1 
onClick="event" something2
<% this is a scriplet tag %>
something3
style="style1">

<h:output text>hello i am text</h:output text>

</h:dataGrid>
```

what i want is to extract(and store it somewhere) the part from "<" to ">" where:

```
< - is the one in "<h:dataGrid"
> - is the one in "style1>" and not the('>') one that appears in the end 
    of "</h:dataGrid>" or "<h:output text>" or "</h:output text>"
```

problem is the text b/w  &&  is in multi-line...&& there are scriplet tags in between them..
so i don't know how to extract this particular string..
i tried using using some regular expressions but couldn't find the exact one..

(this was just an example && instead of this "" tag it can be anything
like again in this line :

```
<h:output text>hello i am text</h:output text>
```

i want to extract the string from  "<"  till  ">"  where :

```
< - is the one in starting of "<h:output text>"
> - is the one in ending of "<h:output text>" and not the one in "</h:output text>"
```

however the difference b/w this exmple and the above mentioned one is that this one is not multi-line and doesn't contains any scriplet tags 
)

Can someone please help me out on this..any specific approach or regex??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read your text char by char. When you reach your opening `<` start a counter and begin adding chars to a `StringBuilder`. As you hit more `<`s increment your counter and decrement on any `>`. If your counter reaches 0 exit your loop and return StringBuilder.toString().

Answer (score 1):

You can try regex but you may need to write a method to sort that for you by keeping track of how many open tags and close tags occur... but for regex: < (.*?) >  <--- This will search for everything between <  and  > note: the space as I see in your above example the tags are separated by <+space. You will also have to escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex, but the basics of any regex you use must be to have a *reluctant* quantifier, eg `.*?`, which won't consume past the first match, whereas a *greedy* quantifier eg `.*` will.

Here's a one-liner:

```
String target = jsp.replaceAll("(?s)^.*?(<.*?[^%]>).*", "$1");
```

This matches everything between and including the first "<" and the first ">" that isn't preceded by "%" and extracts it (by removing the rest).